# Question on proof of $1+2+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ by induction.

Tags: induction

I saw some video where it needs to prove $1+2+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ inductively. So it has to be true if $k=1$ and $k+1$ are true.

So, for $k=1$:

$$1=\frac{1(1+1)}{2}=\frac{1(2)}{2}=\frac{2}{2}=1$$

it is valid.

For $k+1$ here is the proof he does:

$$
\begin{align}
1+2+\dots+k+k+1&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}    &(1)\\
\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+k+1&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}  &(2)\\
&=\frac{k^2+2k+k+2}{2}&(3)\\
&=\frac{k^2+3k+2}{2}&(4)\\
&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}&\text{factoring (4)}
\end{align}$$

Therefore this formula is valid for $k+1$.

---

But is this true? I think not. He is just undoing what he have just done. To prove it I think I need to do this:

$$
\begin{align}
1+2+\dots+k+k+1&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\\
\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+k+1&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\\
\frac{k(k+1)+2(k+1)}{2}&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\\
\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}&=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\\
(k+1)(k+2)&=(k+1)(k+2)\\
k+1&=k+1\\
k&=k\\
0&=0\text{ or }1=1
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $k+1$ is valid in this formula.

Is this right or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Why $k = k$ implies that $0=0$ or $1=1$? That's is true for every $k$.

Comment: It's odd to begin with an equality like this. The correct way would be $1+...+k+k+1 = (1+...+k)+k+1 = (k(k+1)/2) + k+1$ etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second way is correct but I would be more carefull and use like this:

$$1+2+...+k+(k+1)=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}+k+1=\frac{k^2+3k+2}{2}=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$$

*P.s: Not use the equality in the first place. The problem using the equality is that you need guarantee equivalence in every step what is not so easy in many problems.*

Answer (score 0):

Proving for sum =k+1

RhS= $\dfrac {(k)(k+1)}{2} + k + 1 $

Which gives

=$\dfrac {(k+1)(k+2)}{2}$

= $\dfrac {([k+1])([k+1] +1)}{2}$

Which means it hold for n and also n+1 !

Answer (score 0):

This proof is at least unlucky written down.

Normally, we start with the claim for $n$ (Here $1+2+\cdots n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$) and then proof the claim for $n+1$.

The correct way is to start with $1+2+\cdots n+n+1=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n+1$ (we assume that the formula is correct for $n$) and show that this is equal to $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$ by simply adding the two fractions.

It is unusual to start with the aim of the induction step and then going back to show that it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You don't to begin using equality!! You must to arrive in this...
$1+2+⋯+k+k+1= $(here you use the induction hipoteses) Than...We start correct:

$$1+2+⋯+k+k+1=**induction hipoteses(ih)**\frac{k(k+1)}{2}**finish(ih)**+**hereyourepeatlikeabove**k+1$$

I hope I've helped.